# what can be done for connection re use?

Tags: c#, postgresql, azure-postgresql

I am using azure postgres sql where I have one of the common method which gives me connection string,

```
protected readonly string databaseConnString = "Host={0}.postgres.database.azure.com;Username={1}@{2};Password={3};DB={4};Ssl Mode=Require";
    

 protected virtual async Task<NpgsqlConnection> GetDBConnection()
    {
        var connString = string.Empty;
        NpgsqlConnection conn;

        try
        {
            //certificate check
            conn = new NpgsqlConnection(databaseConnString);

            try
            {
                //open the connection
                await conn.OpenAsync();
            }
            catch (PostgresException ex)
            {
                
            }
            finally
            {
                //close the connection
                await conn.CloseAsync();
            }
        }
        
        //return connection string
        return conn;
    }
```

and I am consuming above connection string everywhere in the application when again I am using open/close  connection every time,

```
   using (var conn = await GetDBConnection())
        {
          await conn.OpenAsync();
          //do the work
          await conn.CloseAsync();
        }
```

I am using `npgsql .net core library` and came to know that  `PgBouncer` will not help here. How can I minimize the connection open/close and can achieve connection pooling?

Comment: You can set Connection Pooling Settings in your connection string : [Doc](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html#pooling)

Comment: Why did you create this method? Don't outsmart the library's and framework's connection pooling mechanisms. Are you trying to solve a problem with this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Pooling* is controlled by `Pooling=true` in the connection string, however it's on by default.

- When you call `NpgsqlConnectiona.Open` the physical connection will be taken from the pool if one is exists, you don't have to do anything.
- On *disposing* `NpgsqlConnection` it will be returned to the pool to be reused.

By default there is nothing you need to do or worry about.

[Pooling Documentation](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html#pooling)

[image]

Comment: Do I need to add `Pooling=true` in connection string? Is there any article you can share

Comment: @user584018 no you dont, its on by default, you don't have to do anything

Comment: one point when I am doing `await conn.CloseAsync();`, then this connection back to pool. Is this mean I never used existing open connection as every time I am doing open connection and close connection

Comment: If you are using a `using` statement, you don't need to call close `explicitly` though can if you like. You always need to call `Open`. In short your are doing everything right as is